# Initializing multiple classes an the bootstrap process

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I am trying to make a MVC framework just for learning purpose.

At this stage i made a class `Application` which i am thinking to do the bootstrap like set error reporting based on the config as well as setting up $db instance.

I have a common folde structure like models, controllors, views, libraries and core.

In my core i will have classes for Database, Session, Valiation etc.

I am not getting to the point at how can i pass all those instances to the respective class that holds the protected $instance property so that the inheriting models and controllers will have access to them.

For example in my init process i have done

```
<?php
use Core\Config;

class Application
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Load runtime configuration
        require_once 'config/config.php';
        $this->errorHandler();

    }

    private function setDbConnection()
    {
        switch (Config::$config['database']['dbdriver'])
        {
            case 'MySQLi':
                $db = new mysqli(Config::$config['database']['dbhost'], Config::$config['database']['dbuser'], Config::$config['database']['dbpass'], Config::$config['database']['dbname']);
                break;

            case 'PDO':
                $dsn = 'mysql:host='.Config::$config['database']['dbhost'].';dbname='.Config::$config['database']['dbname'];
                $db =  new PDO($dsn, Config::$config['database']['dbuser'], Config::$config['database']['dbpass']);
                break;

            default:

                break;
        }
    }


}

$application = new Application;
```

How can i pass this dbConnection to my core/Database.php so that my models will extend Database.php and will have $db to do queries etc.

Also is it the good idea or i am doing wrong in terms of performance.

Comment: You should try to IoC container Logic Laravel uses, you can have a Static Object which binds keys to object instances or service providers.

Comment: too difficult for me as a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not too late, but you could try to use a singleton context object, this will allow global access to your objects and avoid static classes.

All you need to to is to create the objects you need within the `Application::bootstrap` method and assign them to the Context.

As for the Models I wouldn't directly inherit from the database, rather I'd use composition like shown into the Model class below.

**EDIT**: I'm a bit rusty with PHP, but last time I checked PDO and Mysqli had very different implementations, so I added
a common Database interface and two half implementations, it will allow to switch from an extension to another without polluting the code with useless conditions.

Context.php

```
<?php
namespace Core;

/**
 *  Context singleton class.
 *  Contains 'global instances' reusable by your application
 */
class Context {
    private static $instance = null;
    private $config;
    private $db;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (null == $instance) {
            $instance = new Context();
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    private function __construct() {
    }

    public function getConfig() {
        return $this->config;
    }

    public function setConfig(Config $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function getDatabase() {
        return $this->db;
    }

    public function setDatabase(Database $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
?>
```

Config.php

```
<?php
namespace Core;

/**
 *  Config class, Since you didn't post the implementation
 *  I took the liberty to implement it as ArrayObject
 */
class Config extends ArrayObject {

    public function __construct(array $configurationArray) {
        parent::__construct($configurationArray, self::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
    }
}
?>
```

Database.php

```
<?php
namespace Core;

/**
 * Database interface.
 *
 * Provides a common interface for different PHP extensions
 */
interface Database {

    public function connect();

    public function diconnect();

    public function getConnection();

    public function query($sql);

    public function countRows();

    public function fetchRows();

    // Add other useful wrapper methods here...
}
?>
```

MysqliAdapter.php

```
<?php
namespace Core;

use \mysqli;

/**
 * Mysqli Database Adapter
 *
 * Wraps Mysqli extension
 */
class MysqliAdapter implements Database {
    private $connection;

    public function connect() {
        $config = Context::getInstance()->getConfig();

        $this->connection = new mysqli($config['database']['dbhost'], $config['database']['dbuser'], $config['database']['dbpass'], $config['database']['dbname']);
    }

    public function diconnect() {
        // Implement mysqli disconnection here
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->connection;
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        // Implement mysqli query here
    }

    public function countRows() {
        // Implement mysqli count rows here
    }

    public function fetchRows() {
        // Implement mysqli fetch rows here
    }
}
?>
```

PDOAdapter.php

```
<?php
namespace Core;

use \PDO;

/**
 * PDO Database Adapter
 *
 * Wraps PDO extension
 */
class PDOAdapter implements Database {
    private $connection;

    public function connect() {
        $config = Context::getInstance()->getConfig();

        $dsn = 'mysql:host='. $config['database']['dbhost'].';dbname='.$config['database']['dbname'];
        $this->connection =  new PDO($dsn, $config['database']['dbuser'], $config['database']['dbpass']);
    }

    public function diconnect() {
        // Implement PDO disconnection here
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->connection;
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        // Implement PDO query here
    }

    public function countRows() {
        // Implement PDO count rows here
    }

    public function fetchRows() {
        // Implement PDO fetch rows here
    }
}
?>
```

Model.php

```
<?php
namespace Core;

/**
 * Abstract model, holds a database instance, it's not necessary since you can access it
 * from the Context but this way it will be inherited by subclasses
 */
abstract class Model {
    protected $db;

    public function __construct() {
        // Assign Database object from the context
        $this->db = Context::getInstance()->getDatabase();
    }

    // Model methods if any....
}
?>
```

Application.php

```
<?php
namespace Core;

/**
 *  Application class.
 */
class Application {

    public static function bootstrap(array $configurationArray) {

        // Initialize and put configuration object into the Context
        $config = new Config($configurationArray);
        Context::getInstance()->setConfig( $config );

        // Connect to the database using the right adapter.
        // Remember to set the 'dbdriver' setting or $db will be undefined
        switch ($config['database']['dbdriver']) {

            case 'MySQLi':
                $db = new MysqliAdapter();
                break;

            case 'PDO':
                $db = new PDOAdapter();
                break;      
        }

        $db->connect();
        Context::getInstance()->setDatabase( $db );
    }
}
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Configuration array
 */
return array(
    'database' => array(
        'dbdriver' => '...',
        'dbhost'   => '...',
        'dbuser'   => '...',
        'dbpass'   => '...',
        'dbname'   => '...'
    )
);
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
use Core\Application;

// Not a very good way, but it should serve you 
// well enough during development
$configurationArray = require_once 'config.php';

// Start application
Application::bootstrap( $configurationArray );
?>
```

I didn't test the code, but should be enough to give you the idea

Cheers